# Creating a Spring Web Service using Plain Old XML (POX)

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-ws

So, I'm writing a Spring Web Service for an already-existing application to talk to. I have the service working to where it will receive a request and respond to it but the thing is, the application expects the response to be in Plain Old XML (POX). My response currently has SOAP headers attached to it like so:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <Person>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        </Person>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What I need it to return is this:

```
<Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</Person>
```

From what I've found, Spring is very much capable of doing this and I think it has something to do with `DomPoxMessageFactory` but all the examples I've found have been with old versions of Spring WS like v1.5. Even the POX sample in the Spring distribution was written 3 years ago. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I am also using spring-ws v2.1.2. My code so far very much resembles what you will find here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an [EndpointInterceptorAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/interceptor/EndpointInterceptorAdapter.html) and change the response overriding the handleResponse.:

```
@Override
public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext_, Object endpoint_) 
throws IOException {

WebServiceMessage _webServiceMessage = messageContext_.getResponse();
SoapMessage _soapMessage = (SoapMessage) _webServiceMessage;
// modify the content
```

**But** i am not sure to what extend you could modify the response.

Answer (score 0):

For me, all I needed was this in the java-based configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "messageFactory")
public WebServiceMessageFactory messageFactory() {
    return new DomPoxMessageFactory();
}
```

This means MessageDispatcherServlet will switch to POX instead of default SOAP.

If you're using XML-based config, this should do it:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.pox.dom.DomPoxMessageFactory" />
```

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486140/creating-a-spring-web-service-using-plain-old-xml-pox/39598468?noredirect=1#comment67648293_39598468) by @loshad-vtapkah:

> This modification only works if namespace is specified in request.xml.
>   For case specified on the link you've provided, namespace is omitted.
>   So you will need either set empty namespace for CountryEndpount (check
>   PayloadRoot annotation) or extend
>   DomPoxMessage.createWebServiceMessage() method to update document
>   nodes namespace.

Comment: This modification only works if namespace is specified in request.xml.  For case specified on the link you've provided, namespace is omitted.  So you will need either set empty namespace for CountryEndpount (check PayloadRoot annotation) or extend DomPoxMessage.createWebServiceMessage() method to update document nodes namespace.

Comment: @loshadvtapkah thank you for that comment! I'll add it to my answer unless you want to add it as an answer yourself?

Comment: please do. I do not see a reason to add the same but updated answer.  If you need, I can provide a working code.